# Calculation of header height no resize not working as intended

Tags: jquery, css, responsive

I have a sidebar that I want to make sure is the entire height of the window. To do this I have to subtract the `height` of the header, so I used jQuery to do that.

For some reason, the `$(window).ready()` function is working perfectly, and no matter the size of my page, always makes the `min-height` perfect.  Howeve, the `resize` function only works when I make the page bigger, and seems to undercompensate when I make it smaller for some reason and I don't understand it.

```js
$(window).ready(function() {
  $("#sidebar").css("min-height", document.documentElement.clientHeight - document.getElementById("headerNav").clientHeight + "px");
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  $("#sidebar").css("min-height", document.documentElement.clientHeight - document.getElementById("headerNav").clientHeight + "px");
});
```

Also, I tried it with `height` instead of `minheight` as well, and it still did not work.

Comment: Is the header always the same height?

Comment: Yes, it is always the same height.

Comment: Well then you could just do it with css: height: calc(100vh - 100px); where 100px is the height of the header

Comment: It seems that CSS would make more sense for this, depending on your exact page layout.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using things like em for my text-size, so I'm worried that the header height may be different on different devices.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference, you can dynamically calculate the header height in CSS - assuming that's even needed.

Comment: Maybe, but I would like to do it in JQuery because I may also add things later like notifications that will push down the sidebar and that way I already have a function to resize it.

Comment: Fair enough, but to be honest using JS for layout sizing is asking for trouble. Spending time fixing this in CSS will pay you back in the long run. In either case we can't really help you without seeing a working example of the problem.

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan . Try looking into flexbox, I'm sure you can set up the code to work with css alone and in all the different scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a pure CSS solution would be better suited here and flexbox seem the way to go to me:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: stretch;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.sidebar {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    Header
    <p>
      Even more text here
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      Sidebar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I can't help you with your js as I can't seem to spot the issue, it seems fine to me.